# How to filter list which elements are in non decreasing order

Tags: scala

How can I filter list of other list, e.g.

```
val l = List(List(1,2,3), List(1,2,4), List(9,8,7))
```

to return a List of elements that are not in descending order and sum of elements in the list is odd. So it should return `List(1,2,4)` (sum is 7 and elements are in not descending order).

I was thinking about something like `l.filter( _ < _ ).filter( _ + _ % 2 != 0)` but I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: I personally would write a tail-recursive algorithm or use `foldLeft` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the sorted list is the same as the list itself:

```
val filtered = l.filter(x => x.sorted == x && x.sum % 2 != 0)
```

Comment: A bit more efficient: `def isSorted(list: List[Int]) = list.sliding(2).forall { l => l.head < l.last }`

Answer (score 0):

Tail recursive method as @Luis noted:

```
def isAscendingAndOddSum(xss: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def isAscendingAndOddSumR(xss: List[List[Int]], acc: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = xss match {
    case Nil                                       => acc
    case h::t  if(h.sorted == h && h.sum % 2 != 0) => isAscendingAndOddSumR(t, h :: acc)
    case h::t                                      => isAscendingAndOddSumR(t, acc)
  }

  isAscendingAndOddSumR(xss, List())
}

scala> isAscendingAndOddSum(List(List(1,2,3), List(1,2,4), List(9,8,7)))
val res11: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 4))
```